# Result: v8 request size exceeds limits. Max allowed 1048576 current request is 1309246

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Result: v8 request size exceeds limits. Max allowed 1048576 current request is 1309246.

This is the result i get when i try to send 350kb file 3 times in Base64 format in one request to Parse Cloud Code function. What does it mean? Is it possible to send it somehow? 
It's important for me, because i'm using Parse as my server and i'd like to keep my device independent from file storage because of Parse limits (i want to use external storages like amazon in future).

Comment: Hey have you figured out a solution for this?